# Excel and Visual Basic Barcode In/Out checkout system

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, barcode

I'm using visual basic to create a checkout system in an excel sheet. The sheet will be filled with information for a project, each of the projects requires that we send out a kit. This excel sheet will allow for a barcode to be scanned, when this happens, it checks for puts an "out" time. When that barcode is scanned again it puts an "in" time. The issue I'm having is that if that barcode is scanned a third time, it will only update the out time.

How do I set it up where it will see that an "in" and "out" time have been recorded and thus go the next blank cell in the row and add the barcode + new "in" or "out" time. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is the code I am using.

Code for on the worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call inout
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```

code for the macro

```
Sub inout()
    Dim barcode As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rownumber As Long

    barcode = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2)

    Set rng = Sheet1.Columns("a:a").Find(What:=barcode, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Columns("a:a").Find("").Select
        ActiveCell.Value = barcode
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Date & "  " & Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2) = ""
    Else
        rownumber = rng.Row
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(rownumber, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = Date & "  " & Time
        ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2) = ""
            
    End If
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 2).Select

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All this goes in the worksheet code module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        inout 'use of Call is deprecated
    End If
End Sub


Sub inout()
    Dim barcode As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim newRow As Boolean

    barcode = Me.Cells(2, 2)

    'find the *last* instance of `barcode` in ColA
    Set rng = Me.Columns("A").Find(What:=barcode, after:=Me.Range("A1"), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    
    'figure out if we need to add a new row, or update an existing one
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        newRow = True 'no matching barcode
    Else
        'does the last match already have an "in" timestamp?
        If Len(rng.Offset(0, 2).Value) > 0 Then newRow = True
    End If
    
    If newRow Then
        Set rng = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        rng.Value = barcode
        SetTime rng.Offset(0, 1) 'new row, so set "out"
    Else
        SetTime rng.Offset(0, 2) 'existing row so set "in"
    End If
    
    Me.Cells(2, 2).Select
End Sub

'set cell numberformat and set value to current time
Sub SetTime(c As Range)
    With c
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm AM/PM"
        .Value = Now
    End With
End Sub
```